# Unhide hidden column with the same button as Hide Command

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code on a command button. and once the columns are hidden, I want to unhide it by clicking the same button

```
Private Sub CommandButton16_Click()
    For i = 22 To 145
    
    If Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Cells(3, i).Value = "Quantity" Then
    Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Columns(i).Hidden = True
    CommandButton16.Caption = "Unhide Quantity"
        CommandButton15.Font.Size = 7
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest using a Toggle Button.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Columns(i).Hidden = True
```

With:

```
Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Columns(i).Hidden = (Not Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Columns(i).Hidden)
```

Comment: happy to help, plz accept as answer so others see it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the requirement is to hide or unhide the columns with value `Quantity` base on the caption of the `CommandButton16`, not based on whether the column is already hidden or not.

This is my understanding of the requirements:

1. If `CommandButton16` caption = "Hide Quantity" *(or <> "Hide Quantity", change as required)*
   1.1. Hide column of any cell in Range `[V3:EO3]` that is equal to "Quantity"
   If there was at least one cell in Range `[V3:EO3]` equal to "Quantity" then:
   1.2. Change `CommandButton16` caption to "Unhide Quantity"
   1.3. Change `CommandButton15` font size to 7
2. If `CommandButton16` caption = "Unhide Quantity"
   2.1. Unhide all columns in Range `[V3:EO3]`*(i)*
   2.2. Change `CommandButton16` caption to "Hide Quantity" *(change as required)*
   2.3. Change `CommandButton15` font size to 12 *(change as required)*

*(i)* *Assumes that only the columns of cells equal to "Quantity" in Range `[V3:EO3]` are hidden.*
*Otherwise: * 2.1. Unhide column of any cell in Range `[V3:EO3]` that is equal to "Quantity"

Try this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton16_Click()
Const kValue As String = "Quantity"     'Use Constants to provide flexibility
Const kHide As String = "Hide "
Const kUnhide As String = "Unhide "
Dim Rng As Range, Cll As Range
Dim blHide As Boolean
    
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Material Masterlist").Cells(3, 22).Resize(1, 124) '1 +145 -22     'Set range of cells to be checked

    With CommandButton16
        
        If .Caption = kHide & kValue Then
            
            For Each Cll In Rng.Cells
                With Cll
                    If .Value = kValue Then
                        .Columns.Hidden = True
                        blHide = True
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            
            If blHide Then
                .Caption = kUnhide & kValue
                CommandButton15.Font.Size = 7
            End If
            
        ElseIf .Caption = kUnhide & kValue Then
            
            Rem Use this line if only the columns of cells equal to "Quantity" in Range [V3:EO3] are hidden.
                Rng.Columns.Hidden = False
            
            Rem Otherwise use these lines
                For Each Cll In Rng.Cells
                    If Cll.Value = kValue Then Cll.Columns.Hidden = False
                Next
                        
            .Caption = "Hide Quantity"
            CommandButton15.Font.Size = 12   'Change as required
            
        End If
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Resource used:
[Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range),
[With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)